# Sorting on direct OR nested properties

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sorting

I am trying to enable column sorting on a table in my angular app. The tricky part is that a couple columns belong directly to the item in ng-repeat, and others belong to an object belonging to that item. Here's some sample data:

```
[
    {
        id: 1,
        status: 'active',
        part_number: 'XXX01',
        paValues: [
            {
                2242_max_search_value: 500,
                display_value: 500
            },
            {
                2220_min_search_value: 10,
                display_value: 10
            }
        ],
        includeInResults: true
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        status: 'active',
        part_number: 'XXX02'
        ,
        paValues: [
            {
                2242_max_search_value: 300,
                display_value: 300
            },
            {
                2220_min_search_value: 20,
                display_value: 20
            }
        ],
        includeInResults: true
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        status: 'obsolete',
        part_number: 'XXX03'
        ,
        paValues: [
            {
                2242_max_search_value: 150,
                display_value: 150
            },
            {
                2220_min_search_value: 0,
                display_value: "-"
            }
        ],
        includeInResults: true
    }
]
```

My repeater looks like this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="part in ctrl.parts|orderBy:orderByField:reverseSort" partrow="part"></tr>
```

On my controller I have

```
$scope.orderByField = 'part_number';
$scope.reverseSort = false;
$scope.attributeSort = function(field, reverse) {
    var paKey = controller.findKey(controller.parts[0].paValues, field + "_search_value");
    $scope.orderByField = "paValues[" + paKey + "]";
    $scope.reverseSort = reverse;
};
```

Right now I can sort the table when `$scope.orderByField` is changed to a string name of a direct property like `status` or `part_number`.

The problem is when it is programatically changed to `paValues[0].2422_max_search_value`, which I think should correspond to the `2242_max_search_value` in the first item in the list of paValues, it does not sort and I get the following console error:

> Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token '.2422' is an unexpected token at column 12 of the expression [paValues[0].2422_max_search_value] starting at [.2422_max_search_value].

If sorting is working fine on a direct property, why won't it work on a nested property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just can't start property name with the number. Try change the code to generate not `paValues[0].2422_max_search_value`, but `paValues[0]['2422_max_search_value']`